# How to use registrars(strato.de) email server and host website on aws CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, registrar

I am hosting a static website with **AWS S3 and CloudFront** but came up with the problem that I **can't receive emails on the registrars email server** (strato.de).

The registrar where I reserved my domain name and email server is currently "Strato.de"
In order to host my static website I created a S3 Bucket on AWS and a CloudFront distribution to use TLS/SSL and HTTPS.
I configured my registrar to point to the aws nameservers in the Route 53 configuration, this works perfectly and my website is publibly available.
**The problem I am facing is that my emails are also redirected to the aws configuration because the nameservers transfer all traffic instead of only my website.**
T
To solve this problem I thought about creating an A-record in my registrar and point to the IP of the CloudFront distribution. Unforntunately they don't use static IP-Adresses. Secondly if I use the S3 bucket directly instead of CloudFront there would be not HTTPS.

I am a beginner in this field and just want to receive emails that are sent to the domain name I reserved at the registrar and at the same time host my website via CloudFront.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, I had a call with Strato and they said you have to use their DNS in order to benefit from their mail service.

My advice will be to use Google suite or Zoho who have more experience in the field, as well you will find a lot of articles explaining how to solve this common issue.